# Convergence in $C^\infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Let $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

Show that
$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f^\prime$ in $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

The definition of convergence in $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is that $\mathrm{\partial^\alpha} g_j\rightarrow\partial^\alpha g$ for all $\alpha$.

I think the case $\alpha=1$ is trivial, so maybe I can proceed by induction. Is this a right way to go?
Any hint or comment is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be a little careful with your definition of convergence. After all, consider $f(x) = x^3$. Then your difference quotient is equivalent to $h^2 + 3hx + x^2$. Thus, $(1/h)(f(x+h) - f(x)) - f' = h^2 + 3hx$, and this won't converge uniformly to 0 (Do you see why?) This is why we need uniform convergence on compact subsets. Notice that on compact subsets, this does converge uniformly (do you see why?)

Assuming that you've simply mistated your form of convergence, perhaps you might want to look at the mean value theorem. Realize that your difference quotient is just equivalent to $f'(x_h)$ where $x_h \in (x,x+h)$. Use that and look $\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} - f'(x)$. Do you see how to proceed now?

Comment: Thank you for your help, @Rikimaru. I'll work on it.